# Will Shopify API request trigger Webhook response?

Tags: api, shopify, webhooks

If I send Shopify a request via the REST API, will that request trigger a Webhook on the corresponding topic?

**Example**

If I create a Webhook for the "products/update" topic, and then update a product via the Shopify API, will that trigger a Webhook from Shopify for the "products/update" topic?

Answer (score 1):

Yes; updating a product through the API will trigger the `products/update` webhook.

Comment: Can you please guide us that, how can we identify that webhook has been sent  due to 
our own api call ?

Comment: @Ravi That's not possible

Comment: Thanks Josh, In our case when we get webhook and if it is not because of our own api call than we want to make update call on shopify.
and if it is because of our own api call then we don't want to make update call on shopify .
so Do you have any idea that how can we achieve this ?

Comment: Oh interesting. I'm not sure what the best approach would be. It may be worth asking a new question with more details

Comment: ya thanks Josh, I have already asked the new question but didn't get any reply.